# ASP.NET Server.MapPath not returning full path of a file

Tags: asp.net, path

I have image files stored in "VS_Project\Resources\Images".

When I use the following code:

```
String str = Server.MapPath("a.png");
```

str becomes "VS_Project\a.png".

Why isn't it returning the full path?

Answer (score 2):

You need a `/` before the `a.png`. If `Path` starts with either a forward (/) or backward slash (\), the `MapPath` method returns a path as if `Path` were a full, virtual path. If `Path` doesn't start with a slash, the `MapPath` method returns a path relative to the directory of the .asp file being processed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string str = Server.MapPath("/") + "\\Resources\\Images\\a.png";
```